# Copy an element of array and push it causes "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed." error - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a copy button that has:

```
$scope.copyHeadline = function (headline) {
        var headlineCopy = headline;
        var current_time = Date.now();

        headlineCopy.label = headline.label + ' (Copy ' + current_time + ')';            
        $scope.headlineList.push(headlineCopy);
    }
```

but I get the "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed" error.  I notice that everyone element in the array or list that i have has some sort of hidden property like:

```
$$hashKey: "object:135"
```

which i'm pretty sure is what it's duplicating but I can't change?

I read that I can use:

```
track by $index
```

but what ends up happening is that when I push the Copy button, it also edits the original element that I was copying as well so that doesn't work..

I was also of thinking of just creating a whole new element and writing a function that'll literally copy every element into a new one.. but this Class alone has several subclasses with ALOT of properties. So i guess I just wanted to see if there was an easier of doing it before I resort to that method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because just assigning a reference of the original object to a different variable will not make a copy of it. It just copies the reference to the same object.

[AngularJS copy documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Use:

```
  var headlineCopy = angular.copy(headline);
```

This will make a deep copy of the object.

Comment: it worked!  ty!  just read your edit, so if i understand correctly, because objects are pass by reference, i'm just passing a reference to the variable which isn't copying it at all.. which the angular.copy does.  thanks!

Comment: I was looking for the documentation, that is why first version of the answer was so short :) I am glad it works.

Comment: the answer presented is cleaner than the following but I think it is also good to know..I believe JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) give clean obj too

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that you are not *copying* your `headline` object, merely *referencing* it.

It's difficult to know the full solution without knowing more about your headline objects, but you could try something like this:

```
$scope.copyHeadline = function (headline) {
        var headlineCopy = {};
        var current_time = Date.now();

        headlineCopy.label = headline.label + ' (Copy ' + current_time + ')';            
        $scope.headlineList.push(headlineCopy);
    }
```

Comment: ah ya you're right.  now that it's been pointed out, I did jus realize i'm referencing it and not making a physical copy.